# JObject in C# for independent data fetching of JSON

Tags: c#, json

I am using Json.Net to parse my JSON
This is my JSON:

```
"OptionType": {
    "C": [
        "C",
        "Call"
    ],
    "P": [
        "P",
        "Put"
    ]
}
```

Before this step, when processed, as a result, I would get a value from any of this.
For example Option Type: Call

Whatever value I get, I need it to be transcodified according to the above JSON.

Example: Option Type: C

Comment: your question is bit unclear please edit your question and clearly mention what you need

Comment: I need to transcodify the result based on the JSON. For example: If I get the result as Call for Option Type, I have to check the JSON find the respective key and replace it with the key ie:C

Comment: means if your optiontype is Call then you need to find out its parent key i.e. `C` and then replace `Call` by `C` right?

Comment: Yes. Absolutely. Similarly I have to do this for all incoming values. for example: P: Put.

Comment: The word "transcodify" really doesn't mean anything, please explain in more explicit detail what you want done and why, otherwise you're going to get guesses posted as answer.

Comment: For instance, why shouldn't you replace P with Put and C with Call? Also, if you replace P with Put, wouldn't that mean you would have two `Put` in the array?

Comment: And by "transcodify", are you actually "transcodifying" *some other json file*? The one you've posted is the table of allowed values? You really should buy a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Answer (score 1):

First of all your sample data is not a valid JSON. You need to wrap it to the curvy braces.

If your sample is a part of the JSON object, you can map `OptionType` to the `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`.

To find valid option you will need to iterate this dictionary like in the sample below:

```
var valueToCheck = "Call";
string type = null;

foreach (var kvp in optionTypes)
{
    if (kvp.Value.Contains(valueToCheck))
    {
        type = kvp.Key;
        break;
    }
}
```

Same using JObject with fixed JSON data:

```
var json = @"{
    ""OptionType"":{
        ""C"": [
            ""C"",
            ""Call""
        ],
        ""P"": [
            ""P"",
            ""Put""
        ]
    }
}";

var valueToCheck = "Call";
string type = null;

var ot = JObject.Parse(json);
var objectType = ot["OptionType"];

foreach (var token in objectType)
{
    var prop = token.ToObject<JProperty>();
    var key = prop.Name;
    var values = prop.Value.ToObject<List<string>>();

    if (values.Contains(valueToCheck))
    {
        type = key;
        break;
    }
}
```

Code is not perfect but it is just an idea what to do.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I should use JObject and replace the data. I need to transcodify the result based on the JSON. For example: If I get the result as Call for Option Type, I have to check the JSON find the respective key and replace it with the key ie:C

Comment: You can't use sample json with JObject as it is not valid. And it is still not clear what you want to do. Just found key by value and use it in the any other place or modify your json?

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over properties of `JObject` and then search your option type and then replace your search option with its parent key.

This is custom function can do above task.

```
public static JObject GetJObject(JObject jObject, List<string> optionType)
{
    foreach (var type in jObject["OptionType"])
    {
        var key = type.ToObject<JProperty>().Name;
        var values = type.ToObject<JProperty>().Value.ToObject<List<string>>();

        foreach (var option in optionType)
        {
            if (values.Contains(option))
            {
                int index = values.IndexOf(option);
                values.RemoveAt(index);
                values.Insert(index, key);
            }
        }

        JToken jToken = JToken.FromObject(values);

        jObject.SelectToken("OptionType." + key).Replace(jToken);
    }

    return jObject;
}
```

And you can use above custom function this like

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(@"Path to your json file");

JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

List<string> optionType = new List<string> { "Call", "Put" };

JObject result = GetJObject(jObject, optionType);
```

**Output:**

[image]